# How to count characters on a single html line with PHP

Tags: php, html, count, character

how do I count characters on a single HTML line (not including tags but including spaces) with PHP?

[image]

After I know the max amount of characters on a single HTML line (including space) I need to then count the characters of a link (if there's one there) and characters before|after.

[image]

so with this information:

- max line characters.
- if link: characters before | after and itself.

Html example:

```
    <p>Line one Line one  Line one  Line one Line one Line Line one  Line one 
    Line two Line two Line two Line two <a href="#link">LINK</a> Line two
    Line three Line three  Line three Line three Line three Line three</p>
```

Php:

read line one, count max characters and if link, then

if Link: count link characters plus before | after. 
make array with

```
"before linked text, amount of characters"
"linked text, amount of characters"
"after linked text, amount of characters"
```

Any help or insight would be great! thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Use strlen()

Example:

```
$str = 'hello world';
$length = strlen($str);
echo $length; //returns 11
```

[View Documentation Here](http://php.net/strlen)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I know to use strlen) but how do I count before and after and the link itself?

Comment: Will the link be static or will it change?

Comment: The link will change, most of the time there won't even be one but it could appear anywhere in the line.

Comment: the other problem is not knowing where the line starts or ends in the html